# General web socket client with auto reconnect capabilities

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

This is a web socket client wrapper with auto reconnect capabilities.

First of all, I know I should avoid working with strings to reduce allocation, that's on test purpose. So, ignore the fact that it is an unbounded `Channel<string>`, which is not directly parsing to JSON from `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` (stringifies instead) and doesn't have a max message size.

I want to have a code review on everything else, i.e. the way it starts/stops/reconnects the web socket, the way I use both classes together, etc.

There are two general clients in the code below:

1. `GeneralClient2`. The initial idea was to signal exit by completing the writer as it's preferred by Microsoft and Marc Gravell. In other words, calling `.Complete`/`.TryComplete` on the writer, completes the reading loop (`ProcessSendAsync`/`ProcessDataAsync`).

**Edit:**

I realized completing the writer is not a good idea in this case because:

- It requires the `Channel<T>` to be nullable because a completed writer cannot be reused. This led to nullability checks in SendAsync, which completely killed the point of the channels as I was using them in oppose to `ConcurrentQueue` + `AsyncResetEvent` (similar to what's been done [here](https://github.com/JKorf/CryptoExchange.Net/blob/master/CryptoExchange.Net/Sockets/CryptoExchangeWebSocketClient.cs#L262-L263)). In other words, I want to be able to enqueue messages anytime I want and not to be getting ChannelClosedException because of some bad timing.
- Channels have the best performance (producer/consumer pattern) compared to DataFlow, BlockingCollection and basically anything else. If [SendAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.sendasync?view=net-6.0) is called from multiple threads at the same time, it will throw an exception. It can be avoided using `AsyncResetEvent`/`SemaphoreSlim`, etc. Channels allow us to specify `SingleReader = true`, which acts as a lock. We can make it bounded and restrict it more, so the clien't can't DOS us.

2. `GeneralClient` uses a CancellationToken to abort the websocket - Similar to this [example](https://github.com/MV10/WebSocketExample/blob/6f2fae728bbf371591268976be6b05fb0a10b14c/ChannelWSClient/WebSocketClient.cs#L52), which is well documented, even though, that example first tries to gracefully close the socket and if something went side ways, it then aborts it. You can express your opinion on this one, but I would rather have a review on `GeneralClient2` as it's the preferred way.

```cs
using System.Buffers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using Nito.AsyncEx;

namespace CodeReview;

public sealed class GeneralClient2 : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _url;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);

    private readonly Channel<string> _incomingMessages = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
    {
        SingleReader = false,
        SingleWriter = true
    });

    private readonly Channel<string> _outgoingMessages = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
    {
        SingleReader = true,
        SingleWriter = false
    });

    private ClientWebSocket? _clientWebSocket;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _tokenSource;
    private Task _processingSend = Task.CompletedTask;
    private Task _processingData = Task.CompletedTask;
    private Task _processingReceive = Task.CompletedTask;

    public GeneralClient2(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));
        }

        _url = url;
    }

    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler? Connected;
    public event EventHandler? Disconnected;
    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>? MessageReceived;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _semaphore.Dispose();

        _incomingMessages.Writer.TryComplete();
        _outgoingMessages.Writer.TryComplete();
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        // Prevent a race condition
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        try
        {
            if (IsRunning)
            {
                return;
            }

            while (!await ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
            }

            IsRunning = true;

            Debug.Assert(_clientWebSocket != null);

            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            _processingSend = ProcessSendAsync(_clientWebSocket, _tokenSource.Token);
            _processingData = ProcessDataAsync(_tokenSource.Token);
            _processingReceive = ProcessReceiveAsync(_clientWebSocket);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping");

        if (!IsRunning)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (_clientWebSocket is { State: not (WebSocketState.Aborted or WebSocketState.Closed or WebSocketState.CloseSent) })
            {
                await _clientWebSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Any exception thrown here will be caused by the socket already being closed,
            // which is the state we want to put it in by calling this method, which
            // means we don't care if it was already closed and threw an exception
            // when we tried to close it again.
        }

        await _processingReceive.ConfigureAwait(false);

        Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
    }

    public ValueTask SendAsync(string message)
    {
        return _outgoingMessages.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
    }

    private async ValueTask<bool> ConnectAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting");

        var ws = new ClientWebSocket();

        try
        {
            await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri(_url), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

            Connected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        catch (Exception) // TaskCanceledException & WebSocketException
        {
            ws.Dispose();
            return false;
        }

        _clientWebSocket = ws;

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");

        return true;
    }

    private async Task ProcessSendAsync(WebSocket webSocket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (await _outgoingMessages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                while (_outgoingMessages.Reader.TryRead(out var message))
                {
                    // "SingleReader = true" acts as a lock.
                    // The lock is required because the client will throw an exception if SendAsync is 
                    // called from multiple threads at the same time. But this issue only happens with several
                    // framework versions.
                    var data = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // normal upon task/token cancellation, disregard
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Send loop end");
    }

    private async Task ProcessDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (await _incomingMessages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                while (_incomingMessages.Reader.TryRead(out var message))
                {
                    await ProcessMessageAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // normal upon task/token cancellation, disregard
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Data loop end");
    }

    private Task ProcessMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ProcessReceiveAsync(WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        Debug.Assert(_incomingMessages != null && _outgoingMessages != null);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ValueWebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;

                using var buffer = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(4096);
                await using var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer.Memory.Length);
                do
                {
                    receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.Memory, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    await ms.WriteAsync(buffer.Memory[..receiveResult.Count], CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
                } while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage);

                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                {
                    using var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var message = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    await _incomingMessages.Writer.WriteAsync(message, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                else if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    await CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebSocketException ex) when (ex.WebSocketErrorCode == WebSocketError.ConnectionClosedPrematurely)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WebSocketException prematurely");

            await CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            await StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    private async Task CloseAsync()
    {
        // Cancel loops
        _tokenSource?.Cancel();
        _tokenSource?.Dispose();

        // Wait for the tasks to finish
        await Task.WhenAll(_processingSend, _processingData).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Prevent a leak
        _clientWebSocket?.Dispose();

        Disconnected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        IsRunning = false;
    }
}

public sealed class GeneralClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _url;
    private readonly Channel<string> _incomingMessages;
    private readonly Channel<string> _outgoingMessages;
    private readonly AsyncManualResetEvent _connectionResetEvent = new(false);

    private ClientWebSocket? _clientWebSocket;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _tokenSource;
    private Task _processingSend = Task.CompletedTask;
    private Task _processingData = Task.CompletedTask;
    private Task _processingLoop = Task.CompletedTask;

    public GeneralClient(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));
        }

        _url = url;

        _incomingMessages = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
        {
            SingleReader = false,
            SingleWriter = true
        });

        _outgoingMessages = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>(new UnboundedChannelOptions
        {
            SingleReader = true,
            SingleWriter = false
        });
    }

    public event EventHandler? Connected;
    public event EventHandler? Disconnected;
    public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>? MessageReceived;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _incomingMessages.Writer.TryComplete();
        _outgoingMessages.Writer.TryComplete();
    }

    public Task StartAsync()
    {
        // avoid race conditions
        if (!_processingLoop.IsCompleted)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _processingSend = ProcessSendAsync(_tokenSource.Token);
        _processingData = ProcessDataAsync(_tokenSource.Token);

        _processingLoop = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!await ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
            }
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        if (_processingLoop.IsCompleted)
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Stopping");

        _tokenSource?.Cancel();
        _tokenSource?.Dispose();

        await Task.WhenAll(_processingSend, _processingData, _processingLoop).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Disconnected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
    }

    private async ValueTask<bool> ConnectAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting");

        Debug.Assert(_tokenSource != null);

        using var ws = new ClientWebSocket();

        try
        {
            // This call timeouts in 20 seconds with WebSocketException by default
            await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri(_url), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

            Connected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _clientWebSocket = ws;

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");

        _connectionResetEvent.Set();

        try
        {
            await ProcessReceiveAsync(ws, _tokenSource.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            //  normal upon task/token cancellation, disregard
        }
        catch (WebSocketException ex) when (ex.WebSocketErrorCode == WebSocketError.ConnectionClosedPrematurely)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        _connectionResetEvent.Reset();

        Console.WriteLine("End");

        return true;
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        _outgoingMessages.Writer.TryWrite(message);
    }

    public ValueTask SendAsync(string message)
    {
        return _outgoingMessages.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
    }

    private async Task ProcessSendAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (await _outgoingMessages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                while (_outgoingMessages.Reader.TryRead(out var message))
                {
                    await _connectionResetEvent.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    Debug.Assert(_clientWebSocket != null);

                    var data = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                    await _clientWebSocket.SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            //  normal upon task/token cancellation, disregard
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Send loop end");
    }

    private async Task ProcessDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (await _incomingMessages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                while (_incomingMessages.Reader.TryRead(out var message))
                {
                    await ProcessMessageAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            //  normal upon task/token cancellation, disregard
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Data loop end");
    }

    private Task ProcessMessageAsync(string message)
    {
        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ProcessReceiveAsync(WebSocket webSocket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ValueWebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;

            using var buffer = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(4096);
            await using var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer.Memory.Length);
            do
            {
                receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.Memory, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    break;
                }

                await ms.WriteAsync(buffer.Memory[..receiveResult.Count], cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            } while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
            {
                using var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
                var message = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                await _incomingMessages.Writer.WriteAsync(message, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public sealed class DeribitClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly GeneralClient2 _client;

    public DeribitClient()
    {
        _client = new GeneralClient2("wss://www.deribit.com/ws/api/v2");

        _client.Connected += OnConnected;
        _client.Disconnected += OnDisconnected;
        _client.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client.Connected -= OnConnected;
        _client.Disconnected -= OnDisconnected;
        _client.MessageReceived -= OnMessageReceived;

        _client.Dispose();
    }

    public Task StartAsync()
    {
        return _client.StartAsync();
    }

    public Task StopAsync()
    {
        return _client.StopAsync();
    }

    public ValueTask SubscribeToDeribitPriceIndexAsync()
    {
        string[] subscriptions = { "deribit_price_index.btc_usd" };
        var @params = new Dictionary<string, dynamic?>
        {
            { "channels", subscriptions }
        };
        var request = new JsonRpcRequest("2.0", Guid.NewGuid(), "public/subscribe", @params);
        var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);

        return _client.SendAsync(message);
    }

    private void OnConnected(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OnDisconnected(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(object? sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Message received: {e.Message}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }
}

public class MessageReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MessageReceivedEventArgs(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Message { get; }
}

public record JsonRpcRequest(
    [property: JsonPropertyName("jsonrpc")]
    string JsonRpc,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("id")] Guid Id,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("method")] string Method,
    [property: JsonPropertyName("params")] object Params);
```

It can be executed through the following:

```cs
using CodeReview;

using var client = new DeribitClient();
await client.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await client.SubscribeToDeribitPriceIndexAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

//await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false);

//await client.StopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

//await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false);

//await client.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my observations

### `DeribitClient`

#### `SubscribeToDeribitPriceIndexAsync`

- The re-creation of the `@params` collection for each function call is unnecessary

  - You can create a `static` private field for that
  - I would also suggest to replace `dynamic?` type to `object`

```
static Dictionary<string, object> rpcRequestParameter = new() 
{
    { "channels", new [] { "deribit_price_index.btc_usd" } }
};

public ValueTask SubscribeToDeribitPriceIndexAsync()
{
    var request = new JsonRpcRequest("2.0", Guid.NewGuid(), "public/subscribe", rpcRequestParameter);
    var message = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
    return _client.SendAsync(message);
}
```

### `GeneralClient2`

#### `_processingXYZ`

- Maybe it is just me but it seems really weird to initialize a `Task` field with `Task.CompletedTask`

#### constructor

- I would suggest to check that the provided string is a valid url

  - Either use [`Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformeduristring?view=net-6.0)
  - Or use [`Uri.TryCreate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?view=net-6.0)

#### `StartAsync`

##### `_semaphore`

- I'm not sure why did you protect only `StartAsync` method from race-condition

  - Don't you need to protect `StopAsync` as well?
- Please also spend sometime to find some better name for this field, like `startExclusiveLock`

##### `ClientWebSocket`

- Why don't you make `ws` a class level variable?

  - Passing this object around different methods feels a bit unnatural

##### `await StartAsync()` inside catch

- It does seems like it can be an infinite loop, since the method calls recursive itself without any exit condition

##### `Console.WriteLine`

- I guess this class is intended to be released as a part of a library based on the `ConfigurateAwait(false)` calls

  - You don't know whether this lib will be used inside a WPF application or in an ASP.NET Core app
- Please try to avoid using `Console` class inside a library class

---

**UPDATE #1**

#### `StopAsync`

##### `IsRunning`

- I'm not sure whether or not it is a good idea to expose `IsRunning`

  - It does feel like it is part of the internal state
  - You are just making shortcuts based on its value
- `DeribitClient` does not use that property at all

##### `State: not (WebSocketState.Aborted or ...`

- Turn your guard expression into an early exit

```
if (_clientWebSocket is { State: WebSocketState.Aborted or WebSocketState.Closed or WebSocketState.CloseSent })
     return;
            
await _clientWebSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

- Based on [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.websockets.aspnetwebsocket.closeoutputasync) only the `Aborted` state could cause exception

  - If the documentation is correct then you don't need the try-catch block

#### `SendAsync`

- I would suggest to pass a `CancellationToken` with time constraint to the `WriteAsync` in order to avoid infinite waiting

#### `ConnectAsync`

- The `new Uri(_url)` is error-prone

  - Please validate your input as soon as you receive it
- `catch (Exception) // TaskCanceledException & WebSocketException`

  - Either have a simple `catch` without any Exception type
  - Or use a `when` statement

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is OperationCanceledException or WebSocketException)
```

#### `ProcessSendAsync`

- Here only the `WaitToReadAsync` call could throw `OperationCanceledException`

  - So, you should wrap only that call with the try-catch

```
bool shouldContinue;
do
{
    try
    {
        shouldContinue = await _outgoingMessages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        shouldContinue = false;
    }

    while (_outgoingMessages.Reader.TryRead(out var message))
    {
        var data = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        await webSocket.SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
} while (shouldContinue);
```

#### `ProcessDataAsync`

- Same as with the previous + the `ProcessMessageAsync` could be inlined

```
bool shouldContinue;
do
{
    try
    {
        shouldContinue = await _incomingMessages.Reader.WaitToReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        shouldContinue = false;
    }

    while (_incomingMessages.Reader.TryRead(out var message))
    {
        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
    }
}
while (shouldContinue);
```

#### `ProcessReceiveAsync`

- `Debug.Assert` is unnecessary since the Channels are declared as `readonly`
- It is strange that this method does not receive a `CancellationToken` as a parameter
- I would suggest to split this giant infinite loop into smaller chunks

```
private async Task ProcessReceiveAsync(WebSocket webSocket)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var (messageStream, receiveResult) = await ReadFromSocket(webSocket);
            await ForwardIncommingMessage(messageStream, receiveResult);
            if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                await CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (WebSocketException ex) when (ex.WebSocketErrorCode == WebSocketError.ConnectionClosedPrematurely)
        {
            await CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

```
private async Task<(MemoryStream, ValueWebSocketReceiveResult)> ReadFromSocket(WebSocket webSocket)
{
    ValueWebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;

    using var buffer = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(4096);
    await using var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer.Memory.Length);
    do
    {
        receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.Memory, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (receiveResult.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            break;
            
        await ms.WriteAsync(buffer.Memory[..receiveResult.Count], CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
    } while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return (ms, receiveResult);
}
```

```
private async Task ForwardIncommingMessage(MemoryStream messageStream, ValueWebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult)
{
    if (receiveResult.MessageType != WebSocketMessageType.Text)
        return;
        
    using var reader = new StreamReader(messageStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    var message = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await _incomingMessages.Writer.WriteAsync(message, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

---

**Disclaimer**: I haven't reviewed `GeneralClient` only `GeneralClient2`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I updated `GeneralClient2` and its description as I realized it's better to use a CancellationToken instead of writer's completion (at least in my case), you can find the reason in the question. Btw, the parts you discussed are kept unchanged. And yeah, it will be deployed as a library. That's why it uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere. I will replace `Console.WriteLine`s with `ILoggerFactory` and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.

Comment: About `StopAsync`, it actually might be a good idea to semaphore it. The reason I'm passing objects around to the different methods is because of the nullability. I would have to do smt like `_clientWebSocket!.ReceiveAsync(...)` or `Debug.Assert(_clientWebSocket != null)` at the top, which is more or less annoying when I'm pretty sure that object will not be null in that particular case.

Comment: @nop As I have already indicated in our chat please do NOT modify already reviewed code! You have rewritten `GeneralClient2`'s `StartAsync` in your question.  Now there is a discrepancy between your question and my review.

Comment: I won't do that anymore. I tried to not change the stuff you commented as much as I could.

Comment: @nop I've finished with my review, please check the updated post.

Comment: Thanks! :) I agree that `IsRunning` should be internal. `catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebSocketException or TaskCanceledException)` is that what you meant? Only these two exceptions can be thrown there

Comment: If `SendAsync`/`ReceiveAsync` is canceled, that would lead to an aborted web socket state. I prefer to gracefully close the socket using `CloseOutputAsync` and then cancel both loops `ProcessDataAsync`/`ProcessSendAsync`. It's also not going to wait indefinitely, I tried a lot of use cases with Clumsy. https://github.com/MV10/WebSocketExample/blob/6f2fae728bbf371591268976be6b05fb0a10b14c/ChannelWSClient/WebSocketClient.cs#L47 in other words, it's similar to this example, it's well done and commented.

Comment: The only difference is that he puts a CancellationToken to `ReceiveAsync`. He did that because of the timeout he passed to CloseOutputAsync. I don't think it's required, because the default timeout is 20 seconds. If I add a timeout, it has to be less than 20 seconds in order to trigger TaskCanceledException, otherwise WebSocketException is being thrown. I don't really mind waiting 20 seconds for it, so I keep it simple. The same is valid for `ConnectAsync`.

Comment: @nop The base class of `TaskCanceledException` it the `OperationCanceledException`. So, my and yours `when` clause are the same.

Comment: I just re-read everything you mentioned, and in fact you're right. The while loop at StartAsync is an infinite loop and we cannot cancel it through StopAsync because nothing to cancel it and the semaphore doesn't allow us. I made it `while (!await ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) && !_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)`. https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/faxiheburu.csharp. Unfortunately I cannot have the same semaphore for StopAsync, not sure if I have to create a new one for it.

Comment: I'm trying to make it possible to call StopAsync during StartAsync and cancel that while loop, but I cannot think of a good way. Do you have any suggestions? Lastly, the while loop currently blocks the thread, which shouldn't happen too, otherwise we won't be able to call StopAsync

Comment: @nop If you are `await`-ing the `StartAsync` call and it is in a retry loop for `ConnectAsync` then yes the caller could not proceed. If you want to await it then use an upper bound for max retry attempts (lets say 5).

Comment: I want to retry forever, but make it possible to call StopAsync in order to cancel that trying.

Comment: If that's the case then you should not `await` `StartAsync`, just fire it off.

Comment: I just posted the subscription holder in another question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276661/managing-websocket-subscriptions